# Run As TestNG is not shown for class extending AbstractTestNGCucumberTests

Tags: eclipse, testng, testng-eclipse

[image]Please note that I've searched for this particular question & found couple of them but none of them had scenario related to cucumber integration.

I've a test runner class extending AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.

I've also installed Eclipse TestNG plugin as well 6.12

Also adding entry under TestNG under Run Configuration, didn't help to solve the issue.

Mac + Eclipse 4.7.0

```
@CucumberOptions(features={"src/test/resources/WunderlistAndroid.feature"}, strict = false, format = { "pretty","json:target/cucumber.json" }, tags = { "~@ignore" })
    public class WLSignIn extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{
    @BeforeClass
        public void launchAppiumServer(){
           //code doing desired action
        }

    @AfterClass
        public void killAppiumServer(){
         //code doing desired action
    }

}
```

Comment: What does your class look like ? Can you please provide a sample of that as well ?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan updated question with sample class, please review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that the eclipse TestNG plugin doesn't see any `@Test` methods in your class. I believe the plugin is contextual in nature and hence shows the `Run As > TestNG Test` only when it sees atleast one `@Test` method in your test class. Since the `@Test` method resides in your base class, the plugin doesnt see that and hence you don't see it.

To get past this, you can perhaps add a dummy test method such as the one below and that should bring back the `Run as > TestNG test` option.

```
@Test(enabled=false)
public void dummyTestMethod() {}
```

On a side note: You might want to file this as an issue in the [TestNG project](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse) and see if its worth getting fixed.

Details that can be used for the bug :

If the base class resides within a jar (and has one or more `@Test` annotated test methods) then the eclipse testng plugin doesn't see the child class (`WLSignIn`) the first time. But after one adds a disabled `@Test` method to the child class (`WLSignIn`) the option shows up. This happens irrespective of whether the child class extends from another class in the same project or from another class which resides in a jar (in your case `cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests`)

Comment: Thanks Krishnan for detailed clarification and workaround. It did the trick.  I've opened new https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/349 as well.

Comment: the issue is fixed in TestNG Eclipse Plugin beta channel: http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse/updatesites/6.12.0.201710150301/